# Puppeteer page.evaluate not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to get all button elements from a webpage using the code:

```
const test = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelectorAll("button")
})

console.log(test)
```

When I log the test variable it yields 'undefined', while when I run the following code on chrome's console:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button")
```

It yields the correct amount of elements.

Comment: What do you expect that `test` should contain? If you expect that it actually contains a list of elements of the type `HTMLElement` then no that is not possible.

Comment: @t.niese That is indeed what I wanted test to contain... My end goal is to check all buttons until I find a button with certain innerText and then click it. How can I go about doing it with the limitation you just told me?

Answer (score 5):

You need to do everything that works with the `HTMLElements` in the context of the website (so from within the `evaluate` callback).

At the end of `evaluate` you leave the context of the site you are very limited to what you can return from `evaluate`.

The data you return from `evaluate` has to be [Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description), DOM Elements are not Serializable in a meaningful way.

So you can only return something that is serializable using `JSON.stringify`.

> My end goal is to check all buttons until I find a button with certain innerText and then click it.

Then you probably don't want to use `evaluate`, query for the elements from outside of the sites context using `$` or `$$`

```
let buttons = await page.$$("button")
```

To get the text from the `ElementHandler` you can use:

```
const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, buttons[0]);
```

or

```
const text = await (await buttons[0].getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

A `click` can be performed with:

```
await buttons[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The values returned from evaluate must be [serializable by JSON](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/303#issuecomment-322919968) since puppeteer is returning chrome API calls, try this:

```
const test = await page.evaluate() => {
    let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button"));
    let buttons = elements.map(element => {
      return element
    })
    return buttons; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried if that actually works? I would expect that the result that `test` holds is an array with empty objects (`[{}, …]`).

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tested it myself. It does not even return an array of empty objects. As soon as a not serializable object is contained somewhere in the data to be serialized the result is in `test` is `undefined`.

Comment: @t.niese A part from the syntax being wrong, it actually yields undefined.

Comment: @RiccardoPerego The question was targeting `JoshuaRDBrown` because I suspected that it will work.

Comment: @t.niese So do you reckon there is a solution for what I'm trying to achieve?